# drag an arc after creating a line tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, line, automatic-ref-counting

Here was the code to draw a line. Is it possible to let the user drag a line so that it forms a curve?

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk

# Image dimensions
w,h = 640,480

# Create canvas
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, height = h, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack()

def on_click(event):
    """ set starting point of the line """
    global x1, y1
    x1 = event.x
    y1 = event.y

def on_click_release(event):
    """ draw the line """
    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, event.x, event.y)

def clear_canvas(event):
    canvas.delete('all')

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", on_click) 
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_click_release)
root.bind("<Key-c>", clear_canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Once again thank youuuuu!!! :)))))

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: I did and it didn't work so I was probably doing it wrong so I came here for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an arc you need to track the mouse as it moves across the screen, rather than just the start and end points.

The code below will only create arcs from the bottom left, to the bottom right of a rectangle, but you can add any other arcs you want by changing the `start` angle and the `extent` angle of the arc.

[image: arcs]

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk, ARC

# Image dimensions
w,h = 640,480

# Create canvas
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, height = h, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack()

# curve points
global points
global temp_arc
points = []
temp_arc = None

def arc():
    x = [point[0] for point in points]
    y = [point[1] for point in points]

    return canvas.create_arc(x[0], y[0], x[-1], y[-1], start = 0, style = ARC, width = 2, extent = 180)

def motion(event):
    global temp_arc
    points.append([event.x, event.y])
    if temp_arc != None:
        canvas.delete(temp_arc)
    temp_arc = arc()


def on_click_release(event):
    arc()
    global points    
    points = []

def clear_canvas(event):
    canvas.delete('all')

canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", motion)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_click_release)
root.bind("<Key-c>", clear_canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since the start only is one value I can only have one form of arc? Like I can't have all the different kinds of arcs at the same time? Like if I were to create a line then drag the line I could only drag it in one way?

Comment: That's right, `start` is an angle which the arc is created from, `extent` is the angle of the arc. If you want different forms of arcs you could add conditions to change the `start` and `extent` based the first and the last point.

Comment: so start = (x,y) ?

Comment: Getting the angle the arc starts and ends at is very difficult (I've tried but with little success), you're probably better off having an entry box where the user can enter the start angle and the extent angle.

Comment: Well what about if the user could draw a line, then drag to bend the line in different directions? Or is that too difficult too? (Sorry if I'm asking so many questions this is my first year programming and my school believes in "self study")

Comment: I've made it so the user can now drag the arc while creating it, it still only creates arcs from 0 to 180, but that should be easier to change now